# Issue while installing ruby

Tags: ruby

I am getting the following response when trying to install ruby.  As i am new to this tech, i am struggling to get it resolved.  Any help would be grateful.  Thanks in Advance !!

```
Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
Installing yaml-0.1.4...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at    /var/folders/tn/plvd9hsd2cz5b07805zxdzf40000gp/T/ruby-build.20131224182655.29784
Results logged to /var/folders/tn/plvd9hsd2cz5b07805zxdzf40000gp/T/ruby-build.20131224182655.29784.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/tn/plvd9hsd2cz5b07805zxdzf40000gp/T/ruby-build.20131224182655.29784/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/tn/plvd9hsd2cz5b07805zxdzf40000gp/T/ruby-build.20131224182655.29784
Results logged to /var/folders/tn/plvd9hsd2cz5b07805zxdzf40000gp/T/ruby-build.20131224182655.29784.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/tn/plvd9hsd2cz5b07805zxdzf40000gp/T/ruby-    build.20131224182655.29784/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Start from the beginning: what instructions for installation are you using and what did you type in first?

Comment: might be a corrupted gcc install

Comment: did you see into the **config.log** file?

Comment: Have you tried installing it from packages? It's a quite tricky task to uninstall things that you have installed with `sudo make install`. And that's much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot really figure out from this information. Try to see **config.log**. 
If you are installing first time then try using rbenv. Follow the steps to install Ruby 2.0 :

1. `git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv`
2. `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
3. `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
4. `git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`
5. `source ~/.bash_profile`
6. `rbenv install 2.0.0-p247`
7. `rbenv global 2.0.0-p247`
8. `rbenv rehash`
9. `ruby -v             #This is to check whether Ruby got installed or not`
10. `gem install bundler`